# symfony2 special routes wildcard nothing else

Tags: symfony, match, routes

problem:

need to have urls like this:

```
wall:
pattern:  /{username}/
```

But.. it **match every url** like /Messages/, /Settings/

And only solution which comes to mind is to check if this user exists... and if no redirect to the real /Settings ? But its one select for each page and i dont like it.

Is there any other way? + i also probably need to denied register users with routes patterns? How?

**AND NO I DONT WANT TO ADD TO URL SOMETHING LIKE**  /User/{username}

Comment: It seems rather impossible. Consider that some day you might create page named "sales" and your user database could contain user named "sales". You need to add some prefix (or suffix) to your pattern in order to be able to distinct ordinary pages from user profiles.

Comment: hm... but lets say i would care of it ... how could i fix my today's problem?

Comment: Ok, I think I see a possible pattern here. Each "page" start with uppercase, so Can you constraint usernames to lowercase only, **OR** at least to start with lower case character?

Comment: hm... yes i think i could have all normal pages with first leeter as uppercase (/Messages, /Settings, ) **AND** the usernames like /james /trki /jperovic i would have all like this but ... can i somehow convert it in route? Because what would happend if user would type server.com/JPEROVIC ? Can the route file convert it somehow to server.com/jperovic?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do such conversion. Can you silently enforce the conversion during the registration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my comment, this could be a workaround:

```
pages:
    pattern: /{page}/
    requirements:
        page: "(Messages|Settings|SomeOtherPage|YetAnotherPage)"
wall:
    pattern:  /{username}/
```

Basically, it requires that Page (Settings, Messages, etc) starts with uppercase ([A-Z]) and the rest of page name is not important.

As for the user-profile pages, they should start explicitly with lowercase character ([a-z]).

I don't know if this suffices your requirements...

**EDIT:**

This is in fact a bit simplified solution of @tomas.pecserke. I have just edited routing so all the pages are enumerated in single route.

Comment: hm... at first: InvalidArgumentException: Routing requirement for "username" must be a string. + . even if this woud work seems to be ok to ask from users to type adress lowercase like /jperovic?

Comment: And i think ... i dont even have to put there requirements. I could put all pages routes to the front. Then will come the {username} route and there easily can be /Trki or /trki it will not match the page + when i create new page i will just "register new user with this username". what do you say?

Comment: I have edited the routes but in this case you have all the possible pages enumerated right in you route requirements. This is some what less flexible but it does the job. This solution is actually simplified one @tomas.pecserke gave in his answer...

Comment: As for the `InvalidArgumentException`, I think you need to quote the regex

Comment: you are right, but when i add requirements for wall route and is behind the /Messages route it still match it.. so i removed the requirements... wall is still behind messages route and when i access /Messages it works.. so i will register username "Messages" etc i have just few pages no problem, ... and then this should work good right? Because i will have unique names. But still i would like to ask for what is good your route pages with pattern /{page} and with enumerated all pages?

Comment: There is not actual benefit other than it's shorter to define ;) As for the usernames "Messages" and such, in that case, you will have to prohibit some "special" usernames to be registered...

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend against this approach. You should definetly prefix the route. But if you must do it this way, you can specify other routes first. RouteMatcher chooses the first route that matches the pattern.

```
# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/routing.yml
account:
    pattern: /account
    defaults: # ...
some_other_route:
    pattern: /some_other_route
    defaults: # ...
wall:
    pattern: /{username}/
    defaults: # ...
    # you can set requirements
    requirements:
        username: [a-z0-9]+ # regular expression
```

Comment: hm.. yea i will put them to the front .. and for other people reg exp must be quoted