# How can I allow root-relative routes in Symfony2 (eg: /{slug}) without overriding other routes

Tags: symfony, url-routing

I have an application that manages store location. Our current routes use a `/location/{postalCode}` route pattern.

The previous version of the site allowed for location shortcuts based on a slug using a `/{slug}` pattern.

I load my bundle's routing last (*after* all other routes)…

```
# (File: app/config/routing.yml)
# Locations
# =========
# Note: this is intentionally last because locations must match root-relative
# wildcard slugs (eg: /atlanta /alberta /boston) for location and city pages.
foo_locations:
    resource: "@FOOLocationsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

…and define the shortcut route *last*…

```
# (File: src/FOO/LocationsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml)
# Location Alias/Shortcuts
# ========================
# NOTE: this must be the last route defined so that it does not get clobbered
# by other routes
foo_location_shortcut:
    pattern: /{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: FOOLocationsBundle:Default:shortcut }
```

I figured by loading these routes *last*, it would allow other routes to match *first*. This doesn't appear to be the case. Most (though, not all) other routes will invoke the `FOOLocationsBundle:Default:shortcut` action.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568044/symfony2-special-routes-wildcard-nothing-else) appears to be the closest to an answer I could find, but it seems it is defining explicit matches in the requirements, which won't work for me as these slugs are managed in the CMS.

Comment: have you tried playing with app/console router:match to see in which order the routes are processed and why they all match that one?

Comment: Excellent idea. I hadn't thought of that…

Comment: Routing works the way you expect it to work: first match is a hit. Did you try setting up a requirement such as `slug: .+`?